# How can I send POST request with zip body using WebClient reactive web client

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to POST a request with ZIP (compressed data) body using WebClient reactive web Client.

I created a zip in memory (bytearrayoutputstream) and want to send the zip data in a POST request body using WebClient reactive web Client. The REST API is a PdfReactor REST WebService. The Response is a binary data (pdf).

When I debug my Code I get the following error:
Pooled connection observed an error

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:297) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$writeWithMessageWriters$9(BodyInserters.java:287) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:287) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromObject$1(BodyInserters.java:85) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest.writeTo(DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java:257) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$exchange$1(ExchangeFunctions.java:103) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.lambda$connect$2(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:110) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler.requestWithBody(HttpClientConnect.java:528) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.lambda$onStateChange$0(HttpClientConnect.java:396) [reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) [reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:397) [reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:501) [reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.run(PooledConnectionProvider.java:531) [reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446) [netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) [netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    |_  Mono.error ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$writeWithMessageWriters$9(BodyInserters.java:287)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:396)
```

```
 configuration.json:
    {
    "document": "test.html",
    "addBookmarks": true,
    "addLinks": true
    }

 test.html:
    <html>
     <img src="img/image.png" />
     <div>
    Hallo, hier ist ein Testdokument von <span th:text="${userName}" />.
     </div>
    </html>
```

```
map.put(template, tempBytesArray);
map.put(configuration, configByteArray);

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try (ZipOutputStream zos_ = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
                map.forEach((k, v) -> {
                    var zipentry = new ZipEntry(k);
                    try {
                        zos_.putNextEntry(zipentry);
                        zos_.write(v);
                        zos_.closeEntry();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
               byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();
               BodyInserter<Object, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage>     bodyInserter = BodyInserters.fromObject(bos);
               byteArray = pdfReactorClient
                        .post()
                        .uri(pdfReactorUrl + PDF_REACTOR_URL_SUFFIX)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(bos)
                        .exchange()
                        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono (ByteArrayResource.class))
                        .map(ByteArrayResource::getByteArray)
                        .block();
                zos_.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
```

If I execute the following CURL on command line, I get the result pdf:

`curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary @test.gzip "http://localhost:8080/service/rest/convert.pdf" > result.pdf`.

Same should be translated in Java reactive Code. The **request body** (Zip/asset package) to the PDFReactor is the problem. Kindly help please...

[PDFReactor](https://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html#usingREST)

Comment: The log that you copy&paste is too big, for example, it have information about tomcat start that is not relevant. Could you be more specific with the error in the log?

Answer (score 0):

> Content-Type for PDF is MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF

change the content type as shown below

```
                    pdfReactorClient
                        .post()
                        .uri(pdfReactorUrl + PDF_REACTOR_URL_SUFFIX)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
```

Comment: Hi Pablo & Barath,

Comment: Hi Pablo & Barath,                                                                                          Please I changed the accept media type to your advice:                                             
.post()
                            .uri(pdfReactorUrl + PDF_REACTOR_URL_SUFFIX)
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(bos))
But it reproduced the sane error: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
 |_ Mono.error ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$writeWithMessageWriters$9(BodyInserters.java:287)
 |_ Mono.defer ⇢ reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:396)