# How to compress JSON request body with WebClient?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I need to do a `POST` using `WebClient` and the server requires the body to be compressed. I've checked previous questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568018/how-to-compress-the-body-of-spring-webclient-post-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487919/how-can-i-send-post-request-with-zip-body-using-webclient-reactive-web-client), but none helped me understand what needs to be done.

My code looks something like this:

```
webClient.post()
    .bodyValue(requestBody)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Response.class)
```

I'd like to send the `requestBody` compressed using gzip. We were doing it with RestTemplate and a custom `GZipFilter` but I cannot see how to do it now with the WebClient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have implemented sample code to help you with this. You will need to clean this up and adapt to your needs, but I have tested this and it does work.

The first step is to implement an `Encoder<T>` where `<T>` is the type of the object you want to encode. In my example I am using JsonNode.

```
public class GzipEncoder extends AbstractEncoder<JsonNode> {

    public GzipEncoder() {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canEncode(ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equalsTypeAndSubtype(mimeType) && elementType.isAssignableFrom(JsonNode.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<DataBuffer> encode(Publisher<? extends JsonNode> inputStream, DataBufferFactory bufferFactory, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
        return Flux.from(inputStream).map((JsonNode node) ->
                encodeValue(node, bufferFactory, elementType, mimeType, hints));
    }

    @Override
    public DataBuffer encodeValue(JsonNode node, DataBufferFactory bufferFactory, ResolvableType valueType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
        return bufferFactory.wrap(gzip(node.toString()));
    }

    private byte[] gzip(String value) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
            gzipOutputStream.write(value.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Then you also have to implement an `HttpMessageWriter`

```
public class GzipHttpMessageWriter extends EncoderHttpMessageWriter {

    public GzipHttpMessageWriter() {
        super(new GzipEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> write(Publisher inputStream, ResolvableType elementType, MediaType mediaType, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage message, Map hints) {
        return super.write(inputStream, elementType, mediaType, updateContentEncoding(message), hints);
    }

    private ReactiveHttpOutputMessage updateContentEncoding(ReactiveHttpOutputMessage message) {
        message.getHeaders().add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        return message;
    }
}
```

Now create your `WebClient` as follows (I have added wiretap to confirm gzip is working)

```
WebClient webclientGzip = WebClient.builder()
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(new GzipHttpMessageWriter()))
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(true)))
        .build();
```

Now when I post a JsonNode body with the following, I can see the request going out encoded with gzip

```
webclientGzip.post().uri(uri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(Mono.just(body), JsonNode.class)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked after minor adaptation to our code.